# The usage of "性【しょう】に合う合わない"

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

I came across this sentence:

> 今後の自分には、そういった社交術が必要なのだと頭ではわかっていても、性に合う合わないというのはあるものだ。

Whats the meaning of "性に合う合わない" here? Does it indicate uncertainty or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「[性]{しょう}に[合]{あ}う」 means "to be congenial", "to suit one's taste", etc.

「性に合わない」 means the opposite of that.

It would, however, be pretty awkward if one tried to translate literally 「性に合う合わない」 in OP's sentence.  Note that the 「の」 in 「というの」 nominalizes 「性に合う合わない」.

I would simply use "congeniality" without hesitation for the whole 「性に合う合わないというの」 part instead of using something like "whether or not someone would be congenial to me".

Therefore, my TL of the whole sentence would be:

**"Even though my brain knows that I will need to acquire interpersonal skills like that in the future, there is still such thing as congeniality."**

Answer (score 1):

[性]{しょう}に[合]{あ}う means "fit your preference/style" and [性]{しょう}に[合]{あ}わない means "doesn't fit your preference/style". So [性]{しょう}に[合]{あ}う[合]{あ}わない means "fit your preference/style or not".

The whole sentence means "Even you understand you need people skill from now on, there is a thing to fit your style or not."